# Blocking spam in Google Groups for Business

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-groups

My company is using Google Apps for its email service. We use Google groups for business as shared inboxes for general company enquiries and correspondence, e.g. info@mycompany.com, to which outside senders are able to post to the group and the group members can read through the messages.

The standard Gmail has very good spam blocking and virtually no spam gets through to our inboxes, but unfortunately the same cannot be said for the group. We have started receiving a lot of spam (see below). The only spam features visible in the group seem to be "ban author" which is not an ideal solution given that each one comes from a different email address.

Is there anything we can do better manage the spam we receive? Given these capabilities are integrated into Gmail, it seems plausible they should be applied to group as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure spam moderation settings are enabled for this group - you can find them at this URL: `https://groups.google.com/a/mycompany.com/forum/#!groupsettings/info/moderation`, for a group email info@mycompany.com (obviously replace these values with those appropriate for your real group). 
[image: screenshot of moderation settings]

I recommend sending the messages to the moderation queue and sending a notification to moderators. **However**:

- You need to have at least one moderator configured if you want to get notifications about the spam messages. A moderator is a user with the "Owner" or "Manager" role for the group.
- It can take up to 3 days for Google to notify you about pending messages, so I recommend making a daily process to manually check them (to ensure you're not missing real emails - no spam filtering is perfect). You can check pending messages at a URL like the following: https://groups.google.com/a/mycompany.com/forum/#!pendingmsg/info